What to do with the report from fwts?
I have run fwts on a new notebook and 33 tests failed. What make sense to do with the report ? Developers may probably be interested. I want to install Debian on this notebook. Any good idea will be appreciated.
Firmware Test Suite (FWTS) is a test suite that performs sanity checks on firmware. It is intended to identify BIOS, UEFI, ACPI and many other errors and if appropriate it will try to explain the errors and give advice to help workaround or fix firmware bugs. It is primarily intended to be a Linux-centric firmware troubleshooting tool. More information is here

What exactly is your question? [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment. You might make us familiar with what “fwts” is exactly.
